# How could I receive the entire buffer?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost, boost-asio

I would like to be able to read, or receive, the **entire** buffer that was sent to the socket.

Currently, this is my way of receiving data from the server.

```cpp
std::string Client::Receive()
{
    std::string data;
    data.resize(1024);
    m_sock.receive(boost::asio::buffer(data));
    return data;
}
```

Though if the server sends something larger than 1024 bytes, that won't work.
I'd like to overcome this obstacle.

How could I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't. TCP is a byte-stream protocol. There are no messages. You can receive anything from one byte to your entire buffer size. You have to loop, and if you want messages you have to implement them yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Use an std::ostream_iterator
`https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator`

It's essentially a pointer that you can just keep writing to, keep in mind you need an actual stream to store it to

Answer (score -1):

You can use std::stringstream.

https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

After reading from socket you could use stringstream::str() function to get string from it.

Comment: Like so?
```cpp
std::string Client::Receive()
{
 std::stringstream data;
 std::string buff;

 buff.resize(1024);
 while (m_sock.receive(boost::asio::buffer(buff)))
 {
  data << buff;
 }
 return data.str();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way.